Make the iotedge module update its credentials before they expire
In the support request TrackingID#2408120030005983, it is mentioned that "Edge Hub periodically checks credentials of all connected modules. If any credentials are expired, it disconnects the module and expects it to reconnect".
I want to know how this happens under the hood; like will Edge kill the module and start it again.
Also, how to make the module update its credentials before they expire.
Some code samples would be really helpful.
Background : Have 2 iot egde modules. Inter module communication via direct method is failing at times. Manual restart of module makes it work. Understanding that one of the module is failing to restart/reconnect.
Currently using :

iotedge version 1.4.3,
host os: Ubuntu 20.04,
iot edge module with: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.42.3

